# how to output only male/female students if male/female is selected in select tag html php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a php program where a user will choose dates like october 1 to november 1. After choosing, the program will generate result of students who are sick in between those given dates. Also, I want the user to choose whether he/she only wants to display only male or female results. If the user chooses male in the dropdown, then only male students will be displayed otherwise, only female students. I also want the user to be able to display both genders if he/she picks both.

Here is my program, the only problem I have is that it will display both if I choose male or female. I wanted to only display both gender if the both option is selected.

```
<form action="gen.php" method="POST"> 
        <input type="date" name="date1"> 
        <input type="date" name="date2"> 
        <select name="gender">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="both">Both</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="generate" value="Generate">
    </form>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sickstuds") or die("amasarry can't connect...");

if(isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2']) && isset($_POST['gender'])){
    $date1 = $_POST['date1'];
    $date2 = $_POST['date2'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];



    $query = "SELECT * FROM sickstud";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $found = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($found > 0 ){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                if($row['date'] >= $date1 && $row['date'] <= $date2){
                    if($row['Gender'] == $gender){

                        echo '

                        <table border="1" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="5">
                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['fn'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['mn'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['ln'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['program'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['Gender'].'</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    ';

                    }
                    else if($row['Gender'] == $gender){

                            echo '

                        <table border="1" cellpadding="20">
                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['fn'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['mn'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['ln'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['program'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['Gender'].'</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    ';

                    }

                    else{

                            echo '

                        <table border="1" cellpadding="20">
                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['fn'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['mn'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['ln'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['program'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['Gender'].'</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    ';

                    }

                }
                else{
                    echo '';
                }
            }

        }
        else{
            echo 'no';
        }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test the gender value first

then use it in your query to customize the results...

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sickstuds") or die("amasarry can't connect...");

if(isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2']) && isset($_POST['gender'])){
    $date1 = $_POST['date1'];
    $date2 = $_POST['date2'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];


    if($gender == 'male' || $gender == 'female') // 1 here is the value of the gender it might be 1 or male depends on your form 
    {
      $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sickstud WHERE gender = '$gender' AND date >= '$date1' AND date <= '$date2'");
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if($rows > 0)
      {
        while($i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
          // the rest of what you want to do and then echo
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'No results';
      }
    }
    elseif($gender == 'both')
    {
      $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sickstud WHERE date >= '$date1' AND date <= '$date2'");
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if($rows > 0)
      {
        while($i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
          // the rest of what you want to do and then echo
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'No results';
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Where in your query
**Change your query**

This

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sickstud";
```

To

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sickstud where gender='". $gender."'";
```

**in drop down menu change this line line for both option**

```
<option value="both">Both</option>
```

To this

```
<option value="">Both</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may select from your database the desired result basing on current selection, like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sickstud WHERE Gender='" . $_POST['gender'] . "'";
```

Answering your question. You have three clauses printing out the same:

```
if($row['Gender'] == $gender){
...
} else if($row['Gender'] == $gender){
...
} else {
...
}
```

You probably wanted smth like:

```
if($row['Gender'] == $gender || $gender == 'both'){
...
}
```

Hope it helps.